# SQL group and order

Tags: sql, grouping

I have multiple users with multiple entries recording times they arrive at destinations

Somehow, with my select query I would like to only show the most recent entries for each unique user name.

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM $dbTable GROUP BY xNAME ORDER BY xDATETIME DESC
```

This does the name grouping fine, but as far as showing ONLY their most recent entry, is just shows the first entry it sees in the SQL table.

I guess my question is, is this possible?

Here is my data sample:

```
john  7:00
chris 7:30
greg 8:00
john 8:15
greg 8:30
chris 9:00
```

and my desired result should only be

```
john 8:15
chris 9:00
greg 8:30
```

Comment: We need to see the columns you are selecting.

Comment: Don't use select *, that is your problem here, you have to tell it what record to choose when grouping. Select * is a poor practice anyway. It should never appear in production code.

Comment: Let me guess: MySQL?  I haven't seen another SQL server that allows you to `SELECT *` with a `GROUP BY` clause.  MySQL, on the other hand, assumes you want group by on all columns that aren't aggregates.

Comment: SELECT xNAME, xDATETIME FROM $dbTable GROUP BY xNAME ORDER BY xDATETIME DESC ...... This gives me the same result

Comment: If one of the answers was helpful, you may want to mark it as accepted, by clicking on the green tick next to the answer. This will help you get more answers in the future should you ask further questions on Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 8):

How about something like

```
Select xName, MAX(xDATETIME) AS MaxDateVal
FROM $dbtable
GROUP BY xName
ORDER BY MaxDateVal
```

Comment: i tried to MAX xDATEIME but it gives me the most recent entry for the table, NOT the most recent for each unique xNAME

Comment: Did you try the Query as provided? Also using the **GROUP BY**?

Comment: Yes, if I put in that query all I get is names, and the names aren't sorted by entry time.

Comment: did you mean to put AS between the MAX(xDATEIME) and MaxDateVal?

Comment: You can put AS, but in SQL SERVER it is implied.

Comment: ok didn't know, I tried it and it looks different. Give me a minute to interpret the data to see if it's correct. I'll post the result.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT xNAME, MAX(xDATETIME)
FROM $dbTable 
GROUP BY xNAME 
ORDER BY xDATETIME DESC
```

Comment: I dont think the ORDER BY is required here, just an extra step for the engine X-)

Comment: +1 Agree, just copied his query. But if he wanted it list in order then it would work.

Comment: Provided results does not seems ordered what so all... Check again

Comment: still working on it, at first, I was outputting NOTHING, so I'm trying to figure out what's happening

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your query is that when you use `GROUP BY`, you have to specify the aggregate function for the fields that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause.

You may want to try the following instead:

```
SELECT     u.*
FROM       users u
INNER JOIN (
           SELECT   xName, MAX(xDatetime) max_time 
           FROM     users 
           GROUP BY xName
           ) sub_u ON (sub_u.xName = u.xName AND 
                       u.xDateTime = sub_u.max_time);
```

The above query can be tested as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id int, xName varchar(100), xDateTime datetime);

INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'a', '2010-03-11 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, 'a', '2010-03-11 01:00:00');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (3, 'a', '2010-03-11 02:00:00');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (4, 'b', '2010-03-11 01:00:00');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (5, 'b', '2010-03-11 02:00:00');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (6, 'b', '2010-03-11 03:00:00');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (7, 'c', '2010-03-11 06:00:00');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (8, 'c', '2010-03-11 05:00:00');

-- Query Result:

+----+-------+---------------------+
| id | xName | xDateTime           |
+----+-------+---------------------+
|  3 | a     | 2010-03-11 02:00:00 |
|  6 | b     | 2010-03-11 03:00:00 |
|  7 | c     | 2010-03-11 06:00:00 | 
+----+-------+---------------------+
```

If you want to order the result-set by the `max_time` field, simply add `ORDER BY u.xDateTime DESC` at the end of the query.

Comment: Although I didn't try all of the responses below, this one worked transparently. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(xNAME), MAX(xDATETIME) FROM $dbTable GROUP BY xNAME ORDER BY xDATETIME DESC
```

Comment: `MAX(xNAME)`?  I don't think you can call MAX on a column you specified in a GROUP BY.

Comment: It should return a single row per group, like with MAX(xDATETIME). It may be unnecessary though.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do this:

```
Select 
  xName, xDATETIME 
from 
  $dbTable t1
where 
  xDATETIME = 
    (select max(xDATETIME) from $dbTable t2
     where t1.xName=t2.xName)
order by xDATETIME DESC
```